# Angular observable on error does not refresh interface with ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush

Tags: angular, typescript, data-binding, error-handling, angular2-changedetection

I have a component that uses a service to submit some data.

This component uses `ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush`, but something strange is happening:

- When request **succeeds**: `next` callback is invoked, `formStatus` changes to 'success' and **interface refreshes** with this change.
- When request **fails**, `error` callback is invoked, `formStatus` changes to 'error' but interface **does not refresh** with this change.

As I understand, interface should not refresh because I use `ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush` and I am changing a basic type string variable.

So, ¿why change detection is triggered in `next`?

### Component

When some error happens in the service, I want to receive it inside the error callback.

```js
submit() {
    this.formStatus = 'sending';
    this._service.create(data).subscribe({
      next: () => {
        this.formStatus = 'success';
        // interface refreshes
      },
      error: () => {
        this.formStatus = 'error';
        // interface does not refresh
        console.log(this.formStatus); // prints 'error'
      },
    });
  }
```

```html
<div *ngIf="formStatus === 'success'">
  ...
</div>
```

### Service

Makes a call to the API and catches the error using `errorUtil.handle`, which throws an rxjs Error (because I want to return Observable.error).

```js
  create(requestData: Data): Observable<Data> {
    return this._http
      .post<HttpResponse<CreateResponse>>(
        MY_API.createUrl,
        JSON.stringify(requestData)
      )
      .pipe(
        catchError(this._errorUtil.handle()),
        map(data => this.onSuccessCreate(requestData, data))
      );
  }
```

### Error Handler

```js
handle<T>(): (error: HttpErrorResponse, caught?: Observable<T>) => Observable<T> {
    return (error: HttpErrorResponse, caught?: Observable<T>) => {
      return throwError();
    };
  }
```

I have tried changing `return throwError();` to `throw throwError();` but the behaviour is the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a weird behaviour, I still do not understand why when next is invoked, interface is updated. It should not be updated either.

The right way to do this is using a **stream** to listen to changes in form status.

### Component

```js
type FormStatus = 'clean' | 'sending' | 'success' | 'error';
// ...
private _formStatus$: BehaviorSubject<FormStatus> = new BehaviorSubject<FormStatus>('clean');


set formStatus(status: FormStatus) {
    this._formStatus$.next(status);
}

get formStatus$(): Observable<FormStatus> {
    return this._formStatus$.pipe(
        shareReplay({ refCount: true, bufferSize: 1 })
    );
}
```

```html
<div *ngIf="(formStatus$ | async) !== 'error'">
  ...
</div>
```